# Python While loop print only 2 bytes data from list

Tags: python

I am new to Python.
I am writing simple while loop:

```
response = '11 22 00 33 44 00 00 55 66 00 00 00 00 77 88 00 00'
LocalDataAry = response.split()
exit = 'false'

index = 0
while(exit != 'true'):
   PID = int(LocalSsDataAry[index],16)
   PID = PID << 8
   PID = hex(PID | int(LocalSsDataAry[index+1],16))[2:].upper()
   print PID
   index += 1
```

I am getting output as:

```
1122
2200
33
3344
4400
0
55
5566
6600
0
0
0
77
7788
8800
0
```

But I am expecting my output to display as below:

```
1122
3344
5566
7788
```

How can i do.

Comment: You would have infinite loop since your `exit` doesn't change.

Comment: (1) you process 2 items in one loop iteration, but increment `index` only by 1; (2) you don't treat `00` values any differently, how should your program know that it is not supposed to print them? (hint: use `if`)

Comment: @vishes_shell, is your answer help me to solve the question

Comment: @SurendraKathari i'm not sure, you should try this yourself, but i think it's won't help, because it's not clear what is happening in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the size of first 2 byte data from `response = '11 22 00 33 44 00 00 55 66 00 00 00 00 77 88 00 00'`

Like `11 22` has 1 byte `00`

'33 44' has 2 byte `00 00`
Based on size use `if` statement